# Hybris/Solr multiword-synonyms are working in solr admin ui, but the hybris query seems to be the problem

Tags: solr, sap-commerce-cloud

I hope to find someone who can help with this problem.

I changed the configuration in Solr, so that multiword-synonyms are possible.

I made:

- sow=false in the handler configuration
- autogeneratephrasequery=true (solr 7.2)
- synonymgraphfilterfactory in query time

If i debug a solr query, I see that the configurations are working fine.

**But now the problem:**

In Hybris Shop I get no search results for configured multi-word synonym. It seems that the query-builder translates may be the user query wrong in a solr query.

What is important to check for this?

The hybris-query-builder uses this:

if (values.size() == 1)
            {
                joinedQueries.add("(" + field + ":" + ((String) values.iterator().next()) + ")");
            }
            else
            {
                joinedQueries.add("(" + field + ":("
                        + StringUtils.join(values.toArray(new String[values.size()]), SearchQuery.Operator.AND.getName()) + "))");
            }
        }

```
    if (joinedQueries.size() == 1)
    {
        return ((String) joinedQueries.get(0));

    }

    return StringUtils.join(joinedQueries.toArray(new String[joinedQueries.size()]), SearchQuery.Operator.OR.getName());
```

Is here may be a problem with the AND operator? I tried also only to seperate with whitespace but it did not work.

I show what queries I have debugged in Hybris:

**With AND Operator and multi word "little locker":**

yq=*query*:"(keywords_text_de:(little\^200.0+AND+locker\^200.0+AND+\"little+locker\"\^400.0))+OR+(brandName_text_de_mv:(little\^30.0+AND+locker\^30.0))+OR+(name_text_de:(little\^100.0+AND+locker\^100.0))+OR+(code_string:\         ( and much more, but I have shorten it for you)

**And with seperate via whitespace this:**

yq=*query*:"(keywords_text_de:(little\^200.0+locker\^200.0+\"liege+platz\"\^400.0))+OR+(brandName_text_de_mv:(liege\^30.0+platz\^30.0))+OR+(name_text_de:(liege\^100.0+platz\^100.0))+OR\    (and much more..)

I hope someone sees the mistake and can help me with this problem...